# Docker - Docker Compose stop company level services not base services

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, software-design

I have base services like redis and mongodb which will share will multiple container of same image.

Once client requested new company we will create a new docker-compose file for the requested company with new port and configure apache to point new web port.

For start company-1 service with base services

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose-company-1.yml up -d
```

Same way for company-2

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose-company-2.yml up -d
```

This will create instance for base service and copmany services along with passed configuration for company.

While down the company-1 services

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose-company-1.yml down
```

This will down base services too but base services required by company-2

If we pass follwong command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-company-1.yml down
```

Throw error 
**ERROR: Service 'company-1' has a link to service 'mongodb-service' which is undefined.**

**Can docker-compose solve our problem?**

**How can down specific copmany service not base services using docker compose down**

More information about docker-componse files

docker-compose.base.yml services

- mongodb-service
- redis-service
- general-crons-service
- web-master-service
- master-server-service

docker-compose-company-1.yml services

- web-service-company - Angular APP
- crons-company-services - Crons for company
- mongodb-company - company level mongodb
- communicate-with-master - Looking request from master service
- company-server-server - Company server for web api call

Comment: I do not get you clearly , why not `docker-compose -f docker-compose-company-1.yml down` ?

Comment: @LinPy I need to down only copmapny services using docker-componse not base services `docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose-company-1.yml down`

Comment: @LinPy It just throw error `ERROR: Service 'company-1' has a link to service 'mongodb-service' which is undefined.`
if `docker-compose -f docker-compose-company-1.yml down` beause I linked service with company-1.yml

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extends: option in docker-compose to tackle this

docker-compose-base.yml

```
services:
    base:
    image:
    container_name:
    ports:
```

docker-compose-company.yml

```
services:
   custom:
    image:
    container_name:
    ports:
```

Create a new compose file with the services of both the base and company using

**extends** option of docker-compose

docker-compose-base-company.yml

```
services:
    base:
    extends:
    file: docker-compose-base.yml
    service: base

   custom:
    image:
    container_name:
    ports:
```

You can use docker-compose-base-company.yml to run the services of both base and company

`docker-compose -f docker-compose-base-company.yml up` .

and use docker-compose-company.yml to shutdown the company services alone

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-company.yml down
```

Comment: will base service will keep active?
I think `docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose-company-1.yml down` same just we are extending file.